# Resources Interpreted but Transferred as MIME After Creating HAProxy

Tags: wordpress, mime-types, load-balancing, digital-ocean

I am (trying) to setup a load balancer on DigitalOcean [by following this guide here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-haproxy-as-a-layer-4-load-balancer-for-wordpress-application-servers-on-ubuntu-14-04) using a HAProxy server to roundrobin two WordPress servers.

After several attempts, all my resources (css, js, etc., etc...) are interpreted but transferred with MIME type text/html... So that breaks everything. What should I look into to get this corrected? Obviously the site worked fine w/o errors prior to the new set up.

i.e.

```
"http://myHAProxy-ip/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1"
```

Thnx - Your help is greatly appreciated

--jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that in the tutorial code block:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://haproxy_www_public_IP'); 
define('WP_HOME', 'http://haproxy_www_public_IP');
```

Should have been:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://examplesite.com'); 
define('WP_HOME', 'http://examplesite.com');
```

This took care of the resource interpretation errors